# TypeError: "ModelBase is not iterable"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a small project to practice Django REST Framework (and later a React front-end) before applying the skills I learn to a much larger corporate project.

The project is a back-end API that will allow for someone to see what potential crimes and torts a main character has committed in each episode of It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia. To this end, I've made [this](https://github.com/Nerdenator/IASIP_API) GitHub repository and put a Django project in it.

I find myself getting an error in the browser debug view that I'm not quite able to figure out when I add a new model/serializer/view for the site:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/characters/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'offense_api.apps.OffenseApiConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/person/Workspace/IASIP_API/offense_api/views.py" in character_list
  70.         return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  729.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/Users/person/.virtualenvs/IASIP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  647.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

Exception Type: TypeError at /characters/
Exception Value: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
```

This only happens with the Characters page, which should be the same as my other list view, a list of seasons.

**Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from offense_api.models import Season, Episode, Character


class SeasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    episodes = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Season
        fields = ('season_number', 'episodes')


class EpisodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        fields = ('episode_number', 'episode_title', 'episode_season')


class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ('character_legal_first_name', 'character_legal_last_name', 'character_preferred_name',)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Season(models.Model):
    season_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    season_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.season_number

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.season_number)


class Episode(models.Model):
    episode_season = models.ForeignKey(Season, related_name='episodes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    episode_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField()
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d. %d' % (self.episode_season.season_number, self.episode_number)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d. %d' % (self.episode_season.season_number, self.episode_number)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('episode_season', 'episode_number')
        ordering = ('episode_number',)


class Character(models.Model):
    character_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    character_legal_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True)
    character_legal_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True)
    character_preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='', primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.character_preferred_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.character_preferred_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('character_preferred_name',)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from offense_api.models import Episode, Season, Character
from offense_api.serializers import EpisodeSerializer, SeasonSerializer, CharacterSerializer


@csrf_exempt
def season_list(request):
    """
    List all seasons, or create a new one.
    :param request: 
    :return: 
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        seasons = Season.objects.all()
        serializer = SeasonSerializer(seasons, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SeasonSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@csrf_exempt
def season_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update, or delete a season.
    :param request: 
    :param pk: 
    :return: 
    """
    try:
        season = Season.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Season.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SeasonSerializer(season)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SeasonSerializer(season, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        season.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)


@csrf_exempt
def character_list(request):
    """
        List all characters, or create a new one.
        :param request: 
        :return: 
        """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        characters = Character.objects.all()
        serializer = CharacterSerializer(Character, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CharacterSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from offense_api import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^seasons/$', views.season_list),
    url(r'^seasons/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.season_detail),
    url(r'^characters/$', views.character_list),
]
```

What needs to be modified in order to get around this error?

Comment: I see you've deleted the `Character` model in the `0004_auto_20170327_1633.py` migration.
That may be the source of your problem. Although you have not committed your `0006` migration that I can see the trace of in the `django_migrations` table of your database. Since `Character` seems to be back in the models, can you show us that migration file?

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès I've uploade 0006_character.py as per your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py you are passing the class Character to the serialiser. You should be passing the data characters.

Also don't use preferred name as a primary key it could easily be non-unique